# Xcode 12.3: Failed to re-create a coordinator for com.me.myapp

Tags: xcode

I'm getting the following message while trying to launch simulator

```
Details

Failed to re-create a coordinator for com.me.myapp.
Domain: IXErrorDomain
Code: 29
Failure Reason: Coordinator already exists.
User Info: {
    FunctionName = "+[IXAppInstallCoordinator(IXSimpleInstaller) _beginInstallForURL:consumeSource:options:completion:]_block_invoke";
    SourceFileLine = 313;
}
--


System Information

macOS Version 10.15.5 (Build 19F101)
Xcode 12.3 (17715) (Build 12C33)
Timestamp: 2021-01-25T15:50:20+01:00
```

I also found that it works Ok if i launch it on another device simulator (lets say iphone 11 pro instead of 12 pro) but i'd like to fix this somehow.

What i had already tried:

- cmd+shift+K
- rebooting mac
- quitting xcode

Xcode: Version 12.3 (12C33)

any ideas on how to get it fixed would be appreciated

Answer (score 7, accepted):

On simulador menu:

Device -> Erase all Content and Settings...

Answer (score 4):

I solved it by uninstalling the app from the simulator and running it again.

Comment: It worked perfectly. A simple solution. Thanks @smukamuka

Answer (score 1):

Found the solution:
**xcrun simctl erase all**

Hope it helps someone facing the same problem.

Comment: Thank you for answering your own question!